# biopython installation test fail: ERROR: test_fetch_xml_schemas (test_Entrez_online.EntrezOnlineCase)

Tags: macos, testing, installation, biopython

I'm trying to test the installation of biopython on my Mac and used this command:

```
$ sudo python3 setup.py test
```

Everything is fine except this error message:

```
ERROR: test_fetch_xml_schemas (test_Entrez_online.EntrezOnlineCase)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/zhouyang/biopython/Tests/test_Entrez_online.py", line 205, in test_fetch_xml_schemas
         records = list(Entrez.parse(handle))
    File "/Users/zhouyang/biopython/build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py", line 267, in parse
         raise CorruptedXMLError("Premature end of XML stream")
Bio.Entrez.Parser.CorruptedXMLError: Failed to parse the XML data (Premature end of XML stream). Please make sure that the input data are not corrupted.
```

Also, during the test, these results shows that test_Entrez.online failed.

```
test_Entrez ... ok
test_Entrez_online ... FAIL
test_Entrez_parser ... ok
test_Enzyme ... ok
```

I'm using OS X El capitan 10.11.6 on Mac, I have python 2.7 and 3.5.2 installed and running python3 when installing biopython and related packages.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't care about that error. This test tries to connect to the Entrez server and fetch something from there, and after that check if everything went fine with the data downloaded. For a thousand causes not related with your installation it might have failed while fetching the XML from the NCBI.

If you can use the `Bio.Entrez.efetch()` function from your scripts everything is fine.